# Array iteration with position in puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm planning to implement the possibility to add multiple ssh keys per user.
For a single key, I used:

```
  if ($sshkey) {
    ssh_authorized_key { $resourcename:
      ensure  => 'present',
      type    => 'ssh-rsa',
      key     => '$sshkey',
      user    => $title,
      require => User[$title],
    }
  }
```

For multiple keys, i thought that this might work:

```
  if ($sshkeyarray != []) {
    $sshkeyarray.each |String $singlesshkey| {
      ssh_authorized_key { $resourcename:
        ensure  => 'present',
        type    => 'ssh-rsa',
        key     => '$singlesshkey',
        user    => $title,
        require => User[$title],
      }
    }
  }
```

But the resourcename can only be used once, so I want to give names like "resourcename_1" for the first ssh key and "resourcename_n" for the n-th key.

How can I do this? Can i get the position of the singlesshkey from the array and add it to the resourdcename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the docs [here](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/function.html#each) you can do this:

```
  $sshkeyarray.each |$index, String $singlesshkey| {
    ssh_authorized_key { "${resourcename}_${index}":
      ensure  => 'present',
      type    => 'ssh-rsa',
      key     => $singlesshkey,
      user    => $title,
      require => User[$title],
    }
  }
```

Notice that there's no need to test for an empty array either. Looping over an empty array causes nothing to happen anyway.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: Wow, that's a detail of the `each()` function that I didn't know about before now!  I learned something new today.