# Iterate a puppet resource collector

Tags: resources, iteration, puppet

I am trying to develop a puppet class with a defined resource which creates the configuration for a website.

One of the things that the defined resource has to do is assign the IP address of the website to a dummy interface. Due to constraints of the project this is done with NetworkManager.

So I have to generate a file like

```
[connection]
id=dummydsr
uuid=50819d31-8967-4321-aa34-383f4a658789
type=dummy
interface-name=dummydsr
permissions=

[ipv4]
method=manual
#IP Addresses come here
ipaddress1=1.2.3.4/32
ipaddress2=5.6.7.8/32
ipaddress3=8.7.6.5/32

[ipv6]
method=ignore
```

There is to be a line ipaddressX=... for every instance of the defined resource.

My problem is how do I track the number of times the defined resource has been instantiated so I can somehow increment a counter and generate the ipaddress lines.

Or for each instantiated defined resource, append the IP address to an array which I can later use to build the file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, and I'm not certain that I do, but I think you would want to do something like this:

```puppet
define mytype(
  Integer $count,
  ...
  ) {
  file { 'some_network_manager_file':
    content => template(...)
  }
}
```

And then you would have a loop:

```puppet
$mystuff.each |$count, $data| {
  mytype { ...:
    count  => $count,
    ...
  }
}
```

Key insight here may be that the each function has some magic in it that allows you to get the index if you need it, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43630463/3787051) answer.

Now I *think* that's how it will work, without me spending time researching NetworkManager. If you provide more of your code, I may be able to update this to be more helpful.

Comment: Nice approximation to a solution, thanks! However this is not exactly what I need since not all instances of the defined resource will require a line of networkmanager configuration. I figured out a less-than ideal way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is less than ideal since I would prefer to have it inside the defined resource, but since I instantiate the defined resource with the data from a hash I use said hash to iterate that part.

```
class xxx_corp_webserver (
  Hash $websites ={}
  ){
  create_resources('xxx_corp_webserver::website', $websites)

  # This would be nicer inside the defined class, but I did not find any other way 
  # Build and array with the IP addresses which are for DSR
  $ipaddresses = $websites.map | $r | {
    if $r[1]['enabledsr'] {
      $r[1]['ipaddress']
      }
    }

  # For each DSR address add the line
  $ipaddresses.each | Integer $index , String $ipaddress | {
    $num = $index+1
    file_line{"dummydsr-ipaddress${num}":
      ensure  => present,
      path    => '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dummydsr',
      line    => "address${num} = ${ipaddress}/32",
      match   => "^address.* = ${ipaddress}/32",
      after   => '# IP Addresses come here',
      notify  => Service['NetworkManager'],
      require => File['/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dummydsr'],
      }

    }

}
```